# Allocating 2-D array in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I want to allocate a 2-D array in C at runtime. Now this can be achieved in the conventional manner like this:

```
int *matrix[rows]
for (row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
  matrix[row] = (int *)malloc(ncol*sizeof(int));
}
```

But I found another method, which does the same thing:

```
int (*p)[rows];
p=(int (*)[rows])malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
```

Can anyone explain how the 2nd declaration works? Specifically, what is meant by `(int (*)[rows])malloc`? To the best of my knowledge, `malloc` is used like `(int *)malloc(ncol*sizeof(int))` or `(char *)malloc(ncol*sizeof(char))`.

Comment: The second version is radically different, because `rows` is required to be a *compile-time constant expression*. Only the first version is truly "dynamic".

Comment: For the first case too `rows` is a compile-time constant, you can't declare both number of rows and number of columns dynamically, right?

Comment: @Cupidvogel in **C** you can't declare any of them dynamically

Comment: @icepack: In C you have variable-length arrays. Not in C++, though. And also you don't have variable *types*.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry, you're right. Forgot about C99

Comment: What do you mean by variable-length arrays?

Comment: @KerrekSB Was this originally tagged C++ (instead of or in addition to C)? In C (99, or 2011 if the implementation supports VLAs), both work fine if `rows` is a variable whose value is determined at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you cast `malloc`'s return value to the type **pointer to array `rows` of `int`**.

By the way, in C, the cast of a pointer to `void` to a pointer to object is not requiered, and even useless. You should not worry about these details. The following code works indeed as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int (*p)[rows];
p = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not equivalent, the first allocates an array of pointers to integers, the second allocates an array of integers and returns a pointer to it, you just allocate several next to each other therefore allowing a second dimension to the 'array'.

A simpler version if you don't need the array after the end of the function would be:

```
 int matrix[rows][cols];
```